# CG Image retained from ALAsset Library causing Memory Crash

Tags: ios, iphone, memory, core-graphics, alassetslibrary

I'm adding images from the Asset Library using this code. I'm 99% sure (from Instruments) that the `iref` isn't being released and a new `CG Image` is being retained in memory every time I call this method. However, if I add: `CGImageRelease(iref)` the app crashes.

```
-(void)setBackgroundWithPhotoURL: (NSURL*)photoURL
{
    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
    {
        @autoreleasepool {
            ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
            CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];

            UIImage *selectedBackground = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref scale:[rep scale] orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[rep orientation]];
                if (selectedBackground) {
                    [self setBackgroundWithImage:selectedBackground orColor:nil];
                }
            }
    };
    ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
    {
        NSLog(@"Can't get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
    };

    ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetslibrary assetForURL:photoURL resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:failureblock];

}
```

Comment: What code is in `setBackgroundWithImage`?

Comment: it's a very long chain of void methods, which is too long to post. However, the CG Image is created (I know this from Instruments) before the first line of setBackgroundwithImage is ran.

Comment: @Eric Hi Eric, I am having the same issue, have you solved this?